# Deploy Studio Error - Network Unreachable

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network, mojave

I am deploying some laptops for the users in our company but there is an error which occurs every time.

When I enter the recovery mode, the device tries to connect to the deploy server to retrieve an IP address. Indeed, this fails and shows a message which says

> "Network is unreachable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the MAC didn't detect the Ethernet cable as an Ethernet LAN (because we have it plugged in an adapter) cable anymore rather USB-c so i have just changed in the network utility option the settings to listen to the USB-c port. Then i entered the command

`ipconfig set *interface name* dhcp`

It is not the best solution, but a temporal saver

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see if the network is available before entering Deploy Studio.

From the Recovery Boot Menu (CMD-R boot method) open the Get Help option (it has the Safari logo) and try to navigate to a webpage. If that is unsuccessful, you don't have network access at all.

In that case, one issue might be that you need to register your device/MAC address with your company's network infra before getting access. I worked at a University and this was the case there. If you need help getting the MAC let us know.

Additionally, you could try connecting via ethernet.

Best of luck.